ADF Activity getting executed even when condition is not met
I only want the Log Error  activity to be executed only when any of the set variable activity executes ie: Only when there is an error.But it always executes

Like this

Not sure what is wrong here.How can i configure the pipeline properly so that the Log Error executes only when there is an error.

Currently, when the pipeline succeeds, both set variable activities are skipped. This is an acceptable precondition for log error so it runs.
Should there be a failure then Move File to.. will be skipped. This is when you want log error to run. I think you need to add dependency Move file(on skip) -> Log error. Retain the existing dependencies between the set variable activities and log error to ensure variables are set before logging runs.

This works.... thanks

It doesn't work that way. You are using two Conditional paths : Success and On Skip. Since you have connected both of them with the Script activity, it would run in one of these scenarios:

Both success
Both Skipped
First Succeeded , second skipped
First Skipped, second succeeded

In all of these conditions, it will run the Script activity according to your configuration.
You can try the below approach instead:

Create a variable on pipeline level: flag .
Set the default value for this variable as : False
Cut the script activity
Paste it inside If activity with condition of validating if Flag=='true' then run the script activity in True block
Connect the If activity with on completion conditional path

So even if one set variable turns the value of flag to True , the script activity would run after checking the status of flag variable.
Your solution would look like this:


thanks .. but the above solution is much easier to implement.


I only want the Log Error activity to be executed only when any of the set variable activity executes ie: Only when there is an error.But it always executes

As you are connecting  Log Error activity  with  set variable activity using on skip (grey arrow) which detect if import data is succeeded then set import data activity which id depend on it when import data activity is failed then set import error activity is considered as skipped and it will execute the next dependent activity log error and on success (green arrow) dependency.

On Success (Green arrow) : Activity B only runs if Activity A has a final status of succeeded.
On Failure (Red arrow): Activity B only runs if Activity A has a final status of failed.
On Completeion (Blue arrow): Activity B runs if Activity A has a final status of succeeded or failed
On Skip (grey arrow): Activity B runs if Activity A has a final status of skipped.

For your requirement you only need to connect  Log Error activity to set variable activity with On Succes (green arrow) dependency as below:


For your proposal, both set variable activities would have to run before the script would run.
